# Position window above system tray

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating an app using JavaFX. I want to know if there is a way (aside from estimating the coordinates) to position the window just on top of the system tray time. Right now, my code just estimates the coordinates and adjust the positioning of the window.

Code sample:

```
Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
stage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMinX() + primaryScreenBounds.getWidth() - 400);
stage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMinY() + primaryScreenBounds.getHeight() - 300);
stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

I want to display the window on the lower right of the screen just above the clock on the system tray.
Image:

[image: screen on top of task bar]

Comment: Might be better to do it based on a ratio of the screen width/height, rather than an explicit pixel value to deduct from each.

Comment: @ManoDestra exactly what I wish to do. I was just wondering if there was a way to retrieve a reference of the coordinates for the system tray so I can position my window just on top of it. I posted my answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36673717/1160296), but so far there seems to be some noticeable difference.

Comment: You're subtracting a fixed value in your answer. You need to set the positionX, positionY and width and height of your stage based on a ratio of the overall screen width/height. I don't think there's a property that you can hook into for this, I'm afraid, but I could be wrong. It should be simple enough to estimate a reasonable ratio for it.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, but the size of the stage is supposed to be static. Given that it is static, I can use the width and the height of my window to get an estimate of the correct x and y coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the optimal answer, there might be a better way.

```
Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
stage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMinX() + primaryScreenBounds.getMaxX() - stage.getWidth());
stage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMinY() + primaryScreenBounds.getMaxY() - stage.getHeight());
stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

The result looks like this:

[image]